# I want to raise TypeError when hotel visitor doesn't add valid email address

Tags: python

I want to raise TypeError when hotel visitor doesn't add valid email address  but I'm getting this error instead:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Bex/PycharmProjects/Programmes/OOP/Hotel.py", line 43, in
>   
>       jane = Hotel.from_string("Jane,Doe,janedoe@gmail.com")    File
>   "/Users/Bex/PycharmProjects/Programmes/OOP/Hotel.py", line 15, in
>   from_string
>       return cls(first_name, last_name, email)   File "/Users/Bex/PycharmProjects/Programmes/OOP/Hotel.py", line 25, in
>   **init**
>       raise TypeError("You've entered an invalid email address.") TypeError: You've entered an invalid email address.

```
class Hotel:
    visitors = 0
    rooms = ['single', 'double', 'queen', 'king', 'executive']

    @classmethod
    def display_no_of_visitors(cls):
        if Hotel.visitors > 0:
            return "There are currently {} visitor(s)".format(Hotel.visitors)
        else:
            return "There are no visitors currently at the hotel"
    enter code here
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, str):
        first_name, last_name, email = str.split(",")
        return cls(first_name, last_name, email)


    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        for char in email:
            if char in "@":
                self.email = email
            else:
                raise TypeError("You've entered an invalid email address.")
        Hotel.visitors += 1

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Full Name: {} {}\n Email Address: {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)

    def full_name(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def checkout(self):
        Hotel.visitors -= 1
        return "{} {} has checked out".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)


jane = Hotel.from_string("Jane,Doe,janedoe@gmail.com")

print(jane.first_name)
print(jane.last_name)`enter code here`
print(jane.display_no_of_visitors())
print(jane.email)
```

Comment: It looks like you are raising an unhandled `TypeError`? What do you want to do with that exception?

Comment: On line 11 you got `enter code here` which isn't commented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, Alex!

In your `__init__` it is raising your `TypeError` since it's using a loop to check if every character is `@`, and since not every character is it fails. Instead you can drop the loop and just check it like so:

```
def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email):
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name

    if "@" in email:
        self.email = email
    else:
        raise TypeError("You've entered an invalid email address.")
    Hotel.visitors += 1
```

This seems to work with no errors now.
You also need to remove some extra code to avoid syntax errors at lines 11 and 46. (the `enter code here`)

Comment: I've managed to raise the TypeError now adding the logic in my __init__.
Thanks very much :)

Comment: No worries, if you think this has resolved your question please accept it so others know you're not looking for more answers.